# Ruby Mastermind White Pegs Count

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie to Ruby programming. It is my second OOP project. I have trouble with counting white pegs under certain condition. And Wikipedia says that:

> -A black key peg is placed for each code peg from the guess which is correct in both colour and position.
> -A white key peg indicates the
> existence of a correct colour code peg placed in the wrong position.

I believe that my black peg condition is true, but I can not count my white pegs correctly.
Here is the function code piece:

```rb
def check_guess(code, guess)
    @white_peg = 0
    @black_peg = 0
    index = 0
    while index < code.length
      if code[index] == guess[index]
        @black_peg += 1
        puts "Black => #{@black_peg}"
      elsif guess.any? { |c| code.include?(c) } && code[index] != guess[index]
        @white_peg += 1
        puts "White => #{@white_peg}"
      end
      index += 1
    end
    puts "There are #{@white_peg} white peg and #{@black_peg} black peg"
    is_win?
  end
end
```

I'm invoking above function inside this condition

```rb
  def codebreaker_attempt
    guess_array = @codebreaker.guess_code
     @codebreaker.check_guess(@codemaker.code, guess_array)
  end
```

And lastly my `game` method is here for stop the game

```rb
def play
    codemaker_choose
    (1..12).each do |i|
      puts "#{i}. GUESS\n"
     #puts "Guess array is #{guess}"
      break if codebreaker_attempt == true
    end
```

I'm leaving here repl.it repo of all my codes if you want to inspect.
https://replit.com/@Burakkepuc/Mastermind#main.rb

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails which is not maintained for several years and has unfixed security holes?

Comment: And what does this have to do with RubyGems?

Comment: I think I've tagged them by mistake. I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: Complete rules of *Mastermind* can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -A white key peg indicates the existence of a correct colour code peg placed in the wrong position

I found my answer. The white peg code control should be

```rb
      elsif code.include?(guess[index]) && code[index] != guess[index]
```